# datagrid for vb.net, reading from csv

Tags: vb.net, csv, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I'm working on a homework assignment and I've hit a stumbling block trying to research information. My biggest problem is that I can find lots of info on just datagrids or just CSV files, but not really the two together.

My goal is to add, then average the 14th column of my datagrid after I've read it from a CSV file (on the buttonclick1 event) and to put that average into a label. My 14th column is in String and has $#,### values for that particular column.

Right now, my button1 click event does nothing at all besides putting up an error telling me that the index was out of range, that it must be a non negative number and less than the size of the collection.

So, I realize this is remedial for most of you, but I'm just at an utter loss in regards to how to proceed.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim rowContents As String
    Dim cellContents(20) As String
    'closes stuff
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("F:\1TrevorProjects\MedicalCSV\MedicalProviders.csv")
            MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow)
                    'Dim currentField As String
                    'For Each currentField In currentRow
                    'MsgBox(currentField)
                    'Next
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line" & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped.")

                End Try
            End While
            MyReader.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim total As String = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            total += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = total
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The thing is that CSVs contain all string data.  I would be inclined to create a DataTable with typed columns (ie a number would be stored in an Int32 column).  Add the rows to that and then bind the DataTable to the DataGridView (==DataGrid ???).  Iterating  the datatable to add **numbers**  is then easy.  BTW, is there an error or is it not working as you want?  What is the question

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will update.
The Button1_Click does nothing. I'm really just trying to find code ideas to supplant that particular code.

I have edited the CSV to only have numerical data in the columns that I wish to add together and have changed the column headers (if that's what you're referring to?)

I can look more into binding the two together. I haven't looked or thought on that idea. Thanks! Also, thanks for fixing my formatting!

Comment: did you add DGV columns in the Designer? (is it even a DGV?)  What does "throw a break" mean?  is there an error?

Comment: I did! I have 14 columns that show up on the designer window, each with their name and frozen (if that matters).

Err, it was me saying that the program forces me to break the process. So yes, an error lol. I'm so sorry for being bad at this and more confusing than anything else.

Comment: just updated, but to quote in its entirety: An unhandled exception of type "system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" occurred in mscorlib.dll  -- Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: Note that DataGrid and DataGridView are different controls. DataGridView is a WinForms control. DataGrid is a WPF control.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- If the DGV has `AllowUsersToAddRows` as True, your row loop will iterate one too many rows and throw a `NullReferenceException`
- If the target column is #14, the cell count is zero based, so you should reference `.Cell(13)` for the value.

You can easily do the calculation as you populate the DGV:

```
Dim theTotal As Int32
Dim rCount As Int32
...
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow)
theTotal += Convert.ToInt32(currentRow(13))
rCount += 1
```

Then when the loop ends:

```
Dim theAvg = (theTotal / rCount )
```

If the data is in the CSV as formatted currency ("$123,45"), use this instead:

```
theTotal += Decimal.Parse(currentRow(13), NumberStyles.Currency)
```

Typically in a real app, you have to do something with the data, like import to a DB, add cols, drop cols etc.  In such a case, I would avoid populating the DGV directly and use a `DataTable`.  Especially, if the code was going to have to parse a formatted currency back from string in a loop.

That seems overkill for this, though.